# We're Lacking Trivial Questions

Tags: discussion

So, I've been personally noticing that the difficulty of our average challenge has seemed to progress higher and higher as I've been a member. No longer do we see alphabet challenges, nor as many OEIS challenges. I have a question for the community in regards to this progression; is this a good thing? Or is it a bad thing?

## The Good

- Experienced users get more of a challenge.
- Experienced users can use languages they know to compete immediately.
- Experienced users can spend 1 hour on an answer and maybe win.

## The Bad

- Inexperienced users will not want to compete.
- Inexperienced users are basically not getting a chance.
- There's no longer a quick challenge for experienced users to complete, meaning any answer I want to do will take 30 minutes minimum.

Any additional input on this matter? Honestly I even miss competing in simplistic 10 minute alphabet challenges even if they've been done to death.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the premise. There were 6 beginner-level challenges in the past 24 hours.

Comment: I agree with @Dennis.  I'm probably considered a very inexperienced user here, and I both post and see a large number of challenges I could solve within 5 minutes, and reasonably golf in another 10.  Although it is true that my answers tend not to be competitive, mostly because they're in python.

Comment: I also have the exact opposite observation. Trivial challenges have become more and more common and I think we don't need so many of them.

Comment: So how about a `beginners`-tag, to indicate easier questions? The idea is that experienced users just skip these questions. I don't like the idea to exclude users with >n reputation by the rules of the question. This tag is rather some kind of code of honor.

Comment: From another perspective, I firmly believe *"have little chance to win"* and *"will not want to compete"* are not connected. People continue to post answers which may never outrun a solution in golfing language.

Comment: I'm with Dennis. I've actually posted answers to *two* codegolf questions just this week. [Lets Play Rummikub](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132090/lets-play-rummikub) and [The Original Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131852/the-original-number/). I almost *never* touch golf questions (I like reading the puzzles presented, but have almost no interest in solving them or reading the answers).

Answer (score 6):

Back in the Good Old Days trivial challenges were downvoted to oblivion and closed as "Too narrow". An easy challenge was one I could solve on paper in 25 chars of GolfScript while walking home and then debug when I got home for a total of two hours' effort. You may have joined during a local spike in the number of trivial questions,  but the general trend is up.

> - Experienced users get more of a challenge.

*All* users get more of a challenge from more interesting questions. And given that the intellectual challenge is the only sane reason for being on this site, that's obviously a good thing. How many golf courses have par 1 holes?

> - Experienced users can use languages they know to compete immediately.

You've lost me here. If you think that with 20k rep comes the ability to write a 30 char Jelly answer in five minutes then you're wrong.

> - Experienced users can spend 1 hour on an answer and maybe win.

OK, so maybe you're taking about the borderline between trivial and easy? I don't think any of the questions which I consider *worth* winning took less than 4 hours, and sometimes it took longer than that just to get a *working* answer.

> - Inexperienced users will not want to compete.

If they don't want a challenge, they should find a hobby which isn't inherently challenging.

> - Inexperienced users are basically not getting a chance

Here I think you've got it completely backwards. Trivial questions get flooded with optimal answers in ten minutes. My recent question is 36 hours old and has just two answers in Python and two in Haskell. Which gives a newbie more chance?

> - There's no longer a quick challenge for experienced users to complete, meaning any answer I want to do will take 30 minutes minimum.

Good. Maybe we'll be able to find the ones that are interesting to think about because they won't be buried in dross.

Answer (score 0):

While there seems to be disagreement over the premise of the question, I also note that you haven't proposed a solution to your perceived problem. There is one obvious solution. We could make a policy exemption for trivial questions in order to create space for more trivial questions, by allowing reposting of questions which have been deleted having been found guilty of triviality by a jury of high-rep users (20k+) and mods. If any of them *don't* get reposted, nothing of value would be lost.

Comment: NB While this is intentionally provocative, I've tried not to cross the line into trolling.